# Excel Multi =IF statement

Tags: excel

Here is my original line of code for the cell, which works fine:

```
=IF($V$2="Yes",IF((E3+F3)<=2777.78,((E3+F3)*0.09)*0.8,250),IF($V$2="No",IF((E3+F3)<=2777.78 (E3+F3)*0.09,250)))
```

But I only want that being ran if G3>0

If G3<=0 then I want a blank cell or ""

I cannot figure out how to do this though.

Thanks in advance!

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use something like:

```
=if($g$3<=0,"",XXX)
```

(or just `g3` if you want relative cell addressing) where `XXX` is your current expression sans the `=` at the front <sup>(a)</sup>.

If you just want a cut'n'paste job, use:

```
=if($g$3<=0,"",IF($V$2="Yes",IF((E3+F3)<=2777.78,((E3+F3)*0.09)*0.8,250),IF($V$2="No",IF((E3+F3)<=2777.78 (E3+F3)*0.09,250))))
```

(assuming of course that your original expression was valid - I haven't checked that).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> To be honest, I'm not sure why you didn't figure that out yourself, since your current expression already *has* nested `if` statements. But it may be that you didn't realise that. In any case, the solution above should work okay.

Comment: It's about 6 hours past my bedtime. It took me an hour just to write the original expression there..lol..Thanks for the help. WOrked perfect.